# How to put textblock inside scrollviewer by coding behide ? (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, textblock

I have a xaml code like this

```
<Grid>
    <... some grid row and column definitions .../>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock "some attribute" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

I don't know how to tie `Textblock` with `Scrollviewer` in `C#`. I want to use `Textblock` with `Scrollviewer`. 
If you have another idea, please tell me.

Many Thanks for your help. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use the Content Property

```
            var myScrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
            myScrollViewer.Content= new TextBlock();
```

### Edit

or in combination with XAML

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer Name="myScrollViewer " Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
            myScrollViewer.Content= new TextBlock(); // or what ever you want to add :-)
```

Comment: I need to wait for 5 minutes.